# Android determine a few clickable areas of imageview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, game-development

Let's say I have such imageview:

[image]

I want make those arrows clickable and they should be of proper onClick action like label says.

I thought about a solution. I made up my mind to distinguish those area by color (as every arrow has different color), but how to achieve that? Other solution could be distinguishing by xy coordintates of specific area but it would be a harder and cumbersome solution due to supporting different screen sizes and densities.

If it changes something this imageview src is in Vector Drawable XML format converted from SVG.

I am waiting with impatience for solutions :) .

Answer (score 2):

I think that trying to distinguish colors in the same ImageView can be really tricky. I would go for a solution that separates all the arrows in separate components and it will be much easier to identify clicks.

I don't know the feasibility of separating the single image into multiple subcomponents but it will make your life much easier. If you have the arrows separated it is just a matter of playing with the components in the layout in order to put the right constraints between each other to form the whole post with the arrows. You can use ConstraintLayout to rearrange the elements with paddings for instance.

Answer (score 1):

- Actually to overcome the problem of changes in the resolution and
  screen size, you may define the coordination of clickable areas
  relative to the size of the image (i.e.  defining the clickable areas
  as percentages of the image size or the screen size, rather than
  absolute pixel values). However, in this case your clickable area
  would not be in the same shape as your area in the image. Defining
  such area would be complicated.
- Another solution is making texts clickable. In this case the user
  must click exactly on the text which causes another problem in the
  user experience.
- Next solution, is use of HTML. You have a HTML file with your image and a  tag to specify the clickable area. You may use online free websites for this purpose like [this](https://www.image-map.net/). In this case you have to show your image in a `WebView`.
- The next solution is the one mentioned by Luis Pascaul [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75771843/3937935).